# Drupal 7 | Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function _drupal_error_handler()

Tags: database, drupal, migration, drupal-7

I just migrated a Drupal 7 to xampp and getting these erros,

Fatal error: During inheritance of PDO: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function _drupal_error_handler(), 4 passed in C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Newxampp\htdocs\eirinika\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 2739 and exactly 5 expected in C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Newxampp\htdocs\eirinika\includes\bootstrap.inc:2589 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Newxampp\htdocs\eirinika\includes\bootstrap.inc(2739): _drupal_error_handler(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'C:\Users\anton\...', 1317) #1 C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Newxampp\htdocs\eirinika\includes\bootstrap.inc(2739): require_once() #2 C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Newxampp\htdocs\eirinika\includes\bootstrap.inc(2516): _drupal_bootstrap_database() #3 C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Newxampp\htdocs\eirinika\includes\bootstrap.inc(2658): drupal_bootstrap(3, false) #4 C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Newxampp\htdocs\eirinika\includes\bootstrap.inc(2512): _drupal_bootstrap_page_cache() #5 C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Newxampp\htdocs\eirinika\index.php(20): drupal_bootstrap(7) #6 {main} in C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Newxampp\htdocs\eirinika\includes\database\database.inc on line 187

Can find the 5th argument. I know it's a connection issue but i tried everything. Password,Username, port, db name. Anyone any help.

Try changing name, password, port, driver but no solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know it's a connection issue but i tried everything.

Now, it's not a connection issue, but it PHP version issue. it seems you use PHP 8, while your drupal 7 version doesn't suppport it.

it's already discussed [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3200407)

You need to choose one of the following solutions:

1. Downgrade your PHP version, you could find XAMPP with php 5.6
2. Upgrade your drupal 7 to the latest version of drupal 7. (7.98)